# Authorization Code Validation (OpenID Connect 1.0)

Tags: vb.net, identityserver4, openid-connect

I try to follow the following steps to validate an Authorization CODE:

> To validate an Authorization Code issued from the Authorization
> Endpoint with an ID Token, the Client SHOULD do the following:
>
> **1-)** Hash the octets of the ASCII representation of the code with the hash
> algorithm specified in JWA [JWA] for the alg Header Parameter of the
> ID Token's JOSE Header. For instance, if the alg is RS256, the hash
> algorithm used is SHA-256.
>
> **2-)** Take the left-most half of the hash and
> base64url encode it.
>
> **3-)** The value of c_hash in the ID Token MUST match
> the value produced in the previous step if c_hash is present in the ID
> Token.

I have this CODE when I request an Authorization endpoint the first time to try authenticate a user from a WebForms Client :

```
code=0655d48df75629d9fdbd5a060141bf66ca04418a0e762a6a5e6382c2748753af
```

I have this C_HASH too that I can get from the id_token :

```
"c_hash": "QadHSCSim4aHM8q1F1F6Bg"
```

I'm trying to validate the CODE doing the next :

```
Private Shared Function IsValidAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode As String, stringIdTokenPayload As String) As Boolean
    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim BytesPayload As Byte() = Decode(stringIdTokenPayload)
    Dim stringPayload As String = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(BytesPayload)
    Dim deserialized_payload = serializer.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(stringPayload)
    Dim c_hash = deserialized_payload.Item("c_hash").ToString()

    Dim mySHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create()
    Dim authorizationCodeOCTETS = Decode(authorizationCode)
    Dim elemntsToIterate = mySHA256.ComputeHash(authorizationCodeOCTETS)
    Dim length = elemntsToIterate.Length
    Dim hashedCode(length/2 - 1) As Byte

    Dim count = -1
    For Each element As Byte in elemntsToIterate
        count += 1
        If count > 15 Then
            hashedCode(count - 16) = element
        End If
    Next

    Dim hashedCodeLikeString = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedCode)
    If hashedCodeLikeString.Length <> hashedCode.Length
        Return False
    Dim result As Boolean = True
    For value As Integer = 0 To hashedCodeLikeString.Length
        If (hashedCodeLikeString(value) <> hashedCode(value)) Then
            result = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

But I don't get the expected result. I need to get a TRUE value but I get a FALSE. I think that I am doing something wrong but I don't see what it is. Any help, please?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this programming language of yours, but here's the code from OidcClient

https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2

```
    public bool ValidateHash(string data, string hashedData, string signatureAlgorithm)
    {
        var hashAlgorithm = GetMatchingHashAlgorithm(signatureAlgorithm);

        using (hashAlgorithm)
        {
            var hash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));

            byte[] leftPart = new byte[hashAlgorithm.HashSize / 16];
            Array.Copy(hash, leftPart, hashAlgorithm.HashSize / 16);

            var leftPartB64 = Base64Url.Encode(leftPart);
            var match = leftPartB64.Equals(hashedData);

            if (!match)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"data ({leftPartB64}) does not match hash from token ({hashedData})");
            }

            return match;
        }
    }

    public HashAlgorithm GetMatchingHashAlgorithm(string signatureAlgorithm)
    {
        var signingAlgorithmBits = int.Parse(signatureAlgorithm.Substring(signatureAlgorithm.Length - 3));

        switch (signingAlgorithmBits)
        {
            case 256:
                _logger.LogDebug("SHA256");
                return SHA256.Create();
            case 384:
                _logger.LogDebug("SHA384");
                return SHA384.Create();
            case 512:
                _logger.LogDebug("SHA512");
                return SHA512.Create();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```